# How to delete app cache for all apps in Android M?

Tags: android, caching, delete-file

Is there an option to delete the cache of all Apps or certain Apps in Android M ?

Seems like most ways don't work anymore in Android M.

As a reference I used this Code out of this discussion : 
[Android: Clear Cache of All Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507092/android-clear-cache-of-all-apps/14509140?noredirect)

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
// Get all methods on the PackageManager
Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
        // Found the method I want to use
        try {
            long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
            m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Combined with this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

This Code works fine on devices lower than Android 6.0. But on devices with Android 6.0 it results in this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 3, got 2
```

There is an open source cleaner on GitHub, which stopped development with this reason:

> > Partial incompatibility with Android 6.0 and newer
>
> Starting with Android 6.0,  CLEAR_APP_CACHE  permission seems to be no
>   longer available to regular applications and since this permission is
>   required for cleaning of internal cache, Cache Cleaner is not able to
>   clean internal cache on Android 6.0 and newer. However, cleaning of
>   external cache is still supported.

Is there really no way, to delete App Cache on devices with Android M ?

**How does the Google Setting App handle it ?
It can't be the new method:**

```
public abstract void freeStorage(String volumeUuid, long freeStorageSize,
        IntentSender pi)
```

**because I think it does not delete the Cache of certain apps, but of enough apps to clear the expected ram size... But the Settings app can clear the Cache of certain apps**

**UPDATE**
Like the excepted answer explains, there seems to be no way to delete tha App Cache without root on Devices with Android M and above. But I will post it here if I find a way....

Comment: Since Marshmallow, the command `adb shell pm trim-caches 10m` fails with `Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE.` Looks like a bug

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32070819/3919009

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there an option to delete the cache of all apps or certain apps in Android M?

A third-party app cannot delete the cache of another app in Android 6.0+. The protection level of [`Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) changed from "dangerous" to "signature|privileged" or "system|signature" in Android 6.0+. Now, only apps signed with the firmware's key can hold this permission.

> Is there really no way to delete app cache on devices with Android M?

Unless the app is installed as a system app or you have root access, there is no way to delete app cache on Android 6.0+.

> How does the Settings app handle it?

Android is, of course, open source. Lets look at the code. In [AppStorageSettings.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/marshmallow-mr2-release/src/com/android/settings/applications/AppStorageSettings.java) lines 172 - 178 we find:

```
if (v == mClearCacheButton) {
    // Lazy initialization of observer
    if (mClearCacheObserver == null) {
        mClearCacheObserver = new ClearCacheObserver();
    }
    mPm.deleteApplicationCacheFiles(mPackageName, mClearCacheObserver);
}
```

So, the Settings app is using the hidden method  [`PackageManager#deleteApplicationCacheFiles(String, IPackageDataObserver)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-mr2-release/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#l3994-4011). It can do this because it holds the system level permission  `"android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"` ([a permission a third-party app cannot hold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756145/1048340)).

---

**External Cache**

> However, cleaning of external cache is still supported.

This is still possible on Android 6.0+. I haven't looked at the source code for the app you mentioned but I would assume all you need to do is request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, get all installed packages using `PackageManager`, get the app's [external cache directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29), and delete the directory.

---

**Root Access**

Of course, if you have root access you can delete another app's cache. Here is a quick example of using root access to delete *all* app cache. You can use Chainfire's [libsuperuser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) to run commands in a root shell:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : installedApplications) {
  try {
    Context packageContext = createPackageContext(applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
    List<File> directories = new ArrayList<>();
    directories.add(packageContext.getCacheDir());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      Collections.addAll(directories, packageContext.getExternalCacheDirs());
    } else {
      directories.add(packageContext.getExternalCacheDir());
    }

    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("rm -rf");
    for (File directory : directories) {
      command.append(" \"" + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
    }

    Shell.SU.run(command.toString());
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException wtf) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer :) But there is an app in playstore All-in-one Toolbox "play.google.com/store/apps/…;, they are seeking accessibility permission, with that they are able to clean cache of other apps.

Comment: @ChethanShetty Have you found any solution?

Comment: Starting with Android 11, clearing external cache is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

For more information, please see my answer to [Clear Cache of All Apps in Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904654/clear-cache-of-all-apps-in-marshmallow)

In Android 6 (Marshmallow) there is an additional `freeStorage()` method that takes a `volumeUuid` parameter:

```
public void freeStorage(long freeStorageSize, IntentSender pi)

public abstract void freeStorage(String volumeUuid, long freeStorageSize,
        IntentSender pi)
```

Obviously, the new method is showing up first in the returned list of declared methods.

You can change the orginal code so that it looks like this top work in Android 6:

```
PackageManager  pm = getPackageManager();
// Get all methods on the PackageManager
Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    if (m.getName().equals("freeStorage")) {
        Class[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
        if (params.length == 2) {
            // Found the method I want to use
            try {
                long desiredFreeStorage = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Request for 8GB of free space
                m.invoke(pm, desiredFreeStorage , null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Method invocation failed. Could be a permission problem
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris Sherlock, have  you solved using this answer?

Comment: Please help us. if possible. we got same problem from above answer.

Comment: sadly it seems that it does not clear any Cache, but no exception is thrown.

Comment: This won't work because it requires a system level permission. See my answer.