# Disable caching on reader app while opened through Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, caching, android-intent

I need to open my app private files(pdf, txt, etc) with some reader applications by using the android default View intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't need the file be cached to the reader application. Is there any way to do this? Or do I need to integrate the reader library within my app to prevent these caching.

Comment: You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829176/how-to-delete-app-cache-for-all-apps-in-android-m

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the best way is to show the files within my app? Let me know your thoughts on this.@Raghunandan

Comment: yup i guess so. I have not done this before. Looks like its the way to go..

Comment: As a general rule-  there's no way to force any app launched by intent from doing anything.  If you're worried about security, assume the worst case-  that the first thing any app you launch does is post it to facebook.