# Is it possible to clear the android application cache at API 21

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Is it possible to write a function to clear the app cache on my app. I know that I can go to app settings and clear it that way but I want to be able to do that within my own app in code when its finished processing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried [Clear Cache in Android Application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically/23908638#23908638) but the app still shows that the cache is not cleared.

I have also looked at [How to delete app cache for all apps in Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829176/how-to-delete-app-cache-for-all-apps-in-android-m) but have not been able to write something to do this.

I have added `<permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>`to the manifest but this does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try looking at [How to Clear Cache Data in Android Application Programmatically](https://androidcource.blogspot.com/2018/07/clear-cache-data-in-android-app.html?m=1).

Comment: This is the same code as the my first reference above: I have tried Clear Cache in Android Application programmatically and does noit clear the cache.